# Multiple ajax requests results in to logout and on server side garbage sessions are left behind

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session, authentication

I am using PHP Secure Session handling from [Wikihow.com](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Secure-Session-Management-System-in-PHP-and-MySQL) using database storage method and to handle heavy ajax requests simultaneously i a referring to [bulletproof sessions](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-create-bulletproof-sessions) by teamtreehouse.com

I am following it thoroughly but still there is now way i can find out to where i want to reach. When firing multiple ajax request i am getting logged out and my database gets filled with garbage sessions.

I also tried doing it the manner as shown on teamtreehouse.com blog, without using the database method but still i am there only with multiple garbage but live sessions.

Can anyone let me know that what does i require to do or i doubt if there is any changes required on the code provided by teamtreehouse.com's blog. Sorry not so master but i think so.

If any coding is required i will surely provide it.

Thank you

Session start function along with other functions based on tth's blog

```
function start_session($session_name, $secure)
{
    $httponly = true;                                          ## if true it makes sure the session cookie is not accessible via javascript.
    $session_hash_algo = 'sha512';                             ## hash 'algo'rithm to use for the session.
    if(in_array($session_hash_algo, hash_algos()))             ## check if hash algorithm is available
    {
        ini_set('session.hash_function',$session_hash_algo);   ## temporary sets the value of the given configuration option during execution  
    }
    ini_set('session.hash_bits_per_character', 5);             ## sets number of bits per character of hash
    ini_set('session.use_cookies', 1);                         ## Set the session to use cookies
    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);                    ## force the session to use only cookies and not the URL variable

    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params
    (
        $cookieParams["lifetime"],
        $cookieParams["path"], 
        $cookieParams["domain"], 
        $secure,
        $httponly
    );

    if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
        session_name($session_name);                               ## set the session name
        session_start();                                           ## starts the session
        session_regenerate_id(true);                               ## if true regenerates the session id and deletes the old one,
                                                                   #  it also generates a new encryption key in database
        if($this->validateSession())
        {
            // Check to see if the session is new or a hijacking attempt
            if(!$this->preventHijacking())
            {
                // Reset session data and regenerate id
                $_SESSION = array();
                $_SESSION['IPaddress'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
                $_SESSION['userAgent'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
                $this->regenerateSession();

            // Give a 5% chance of the session id changing on any request

            } else if(rand(1, 100) <= 5) {

                $this->regenerateSession();
            }
        }
    }
}

static protected function preventHijacking()
{
    if(!isset($_SESSION['IPaddress']) || !isset($_SESSION['userAgent']))
        return false;

    if ($_SESSION['IPaddress'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
        return false;

    if( $_SESSION['userAgent'] != $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
        return false;

    return true;
}

static function regenerateSession()
{
    // If this session is obsolete it means there already is a new id
    if(isset($_SESSION['OBSOLETE']) || $_SESSION['OBSOLETE'] == true)
        return;

    // Set current session to expire in 10 seconds
    $_SESSION['OBSOLETE'] = true;
    $_SESSION['EXPIRES'] = time() + 10;

    // Create new session without destroying the old one
    session_regenerate_id(false);

    // Grab current session ID and close both sessions to allow other scripts to use them
    $newSession = session_id();
    session_write_close();

    // Set session ID to the new one, and start it back up again
    session_id($newSession);
    session_start();

    // Now we unset the obsolete and expiration values for the session we want to keep
    unset($_SESSION['OBSOLETE']);
    unset($_SESSION['EXPIRES']);
}

static protected function validateSession()
{
    if( isset($_SESSION['OBSOLETE']) && !isset($_SESSION['EXPIRES']) )
        return false;

    if(isset($_SESSION['EXPIRES']) && $_SESSION['EXPIRES'] < time())
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Post what you have tried

Comment: Sure just give me some time